# Is there a fix for Joomla's module/page class suffix "leading space" issue?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla-extensions

If you know and use Joomla you will know that a common "problem" that arises is that those unfamiliar with Joomla (and airheads like me) often foget to put a leading space before adding a new class suffix to a module or page. Knowing just enough PHP to be dangerous, it strikes me that this is an easy enough fix by concatenating a simple empty space to any new class entered. I know that the geniuses behind Joomla couldn't have overlooked such a common and simple fix, yet for me starting out creating some pretty awesome Joomla templates, it strikes me that implementing a global fix for this using overrides (if poss) might potentially reduce future support hours. Can anybody persuade me not to do this and please explain the reasons why? I get that very occasionally a person may wish to append to an existing class such as modifying "existingClass" to "existingClassModified" but is that really such a need to warrant widespread frustration the rest of the time? Of course, that would break any styling on "existingClass" anyway! Or, is that the logic? To create a redundant class as a kind of element specific css reset?

Comment: I'm tired so sorry to trying to clarify what you're saying. So you want to know why there isn't a fix for when someone accidentally may forget to add a space between each class?

Comment: Yes, in a nutsehll, since it is so easy to fix in the php code that is core to Joomla, and such a common noob problem, why wasn't it fixed long ago? Leads me to assume that it must have some value as it is and has been deliberately left alone - so I dont want to provide a fix for it in my template if it will create more harm than good.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read what you said. No I am not asking why there isn't a fix for when somebody forgets to add a space BETWEEN EACH class - but IMHO having to add a space BEFORE entering a class is pretty quirky. I mean, do you usually and instinctively hit space before typing into a text field? One usually assumes a value entered into a text field will be automatically formatted and not require a leading space to prevent it merging into an existing value.

Answer (score 3):

I have not had this problem before as I don't tend to use a lot of module class suffixes, however having looked at the documentation for [Using Class Suffixes](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Class_Suffixes), it's required that you add a leading space as there might be a class already there.

For example, lets say you install a fresh copy of Joomla and you inspect the template and see the following:

```
<div class="position-left">
```

If you add a module class suffix such as "test", without a space and inspect the element again, it will show as:

```
<div class="position-lefttest">
```

I do however see where you're coming from as people are not expected to know this. I think rather than adding a fix which would require detecting all module positions to see if they already have a class or not, is have a little notification next to the module class suffix input field to remind people.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't really see the difference. Firstly, you highlight an interesting point, which is that the user has no idea whether a class (a first existing class) is already applied or not so the resulting html would easily become class="  myClass" which is still valid if a little unsightly. Since that is the case, a simple concatenation of a empty string to the user class variable is all that is needed. However, as I said earlier, what I was really asking is if people were using the current quirk more as an element-specific css reset - which would void either approach

Comment: You can get two completely different results by leaving a space or not and that is a feature and not accidental.  Sometimes you want to have "tag-15"  be dynamically generated and sometimes you want to have "tag hot" apply two separate classes depending on what's available.  THe occasional empty space inside quote marks is well worth this flexibility for power users.  Not to self promote but here's an article http://officialjoomlabook.com/elin-waring-official-joomla-book-blog/styling-tags.

Comment: @Lodder I think instead of saying it is required you should say that "usually" you would.  It's not required at all depending what you want to do you may not want to leave a space.